# angular material 2 date picker auto open on focus

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How angular material 2 date picker can be configured to be opened automatically on focus? I didn't find anything in the documentation at https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview.

Current html is like this:

```html
 <input [mdDatepicker]="myDatepicker" id="inputWeekEnding" name="inputWeekEnding" type="text" class="form-control" show-button-bar="false"
      [(ngModel)]="weekEnding" [mdDatepickerFilter]="weekEndingPickerFilter" (ngModelChange)="weekEndingChanged()"
              required>
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" [mdDatepickerToggle]="myDatepicker">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>              
  </button>
</span>
<md-datepicker #myDatepicker md-open-on-focus ></md-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`mdDatepicker` provides method `open()` in order to open it manually doe developers. You can invoke it at `md-input`'s focus event. See **[docs(Method of MatDatepicker)](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker)**.

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v59qxb?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.ts)**(*included demo for opening on focus and opening in typescript*)

Comment: I prefer using (click) event instead of (focus), because if you close the datepicker without losing the focus, you must blur and focus again to open the calendar again

Answer (score 39):

As per @angular/material2 v7.0.1 I've been able to handle the input focus correctly by...

- adding `(focus)="picker.open()"` on `matInput` input element to trigger the datepicker opening on focus
- adding `(closed)="input.blur()"` on `mat-datepicker` element so it could remove the focus on the input once the date-picker is closed

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #input [matDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" formControlName="yourControlName">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker (closed)="input.blur()"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The other answers are missing the `(closed)="input.blur()"`-option.

Comment: When `touchUi` is activated in `mat-datepicker` after selecting a date it generates an infinite blink. Did it happen to someone else?

Comment: @PacoZevallos I've got the same problem

Comment: I would add a (click)="picker.open()" to make sure the picker is also opened if focus is kept on input because user is clicking on it.

Answer (score 5):

For the new Angular & Material (5 and above) it should something like this.
The link in question points to up-to-date documentation, but uses code from Angular 2, which might be confusing to newbies.

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" formControlName="yourControlName">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I tried this but when I close the datepicker, it then takes two clicks elsewhere on the page to 'defocus' the associated <input> guy... O.o

Comment: see my answer to remove focus when the calendar is closed