# Open angular mat-datepicker from typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I have a select like this :

```
 <mat-select placeholder="..." (change)="onChange($event.value)">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
        {{ option }}
     </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
 <div class="disable">
    <mat-form-field>
       <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
       <mat-datepicker #picker ></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

disable class just hide the contain of the div.

In my onChange($event) :

```
onChange(value) {
   if(value === 'someValue'){
       openDatePicker() //How to do this ??
   }
}
```

If a specific value is selected i'd like to open the date picker.
Is that possible to do this from typescript ?

Thanks for your response

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874705/angular-material-2-date-picker-auto-open-on-focus/45874934#45874934 and https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api#MatDatepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create object of date picker using `ViewChild` in **TS** as:

```
@ViewChild('picker') datePicker: MatDatepicker;
```

Use predefined method `open` of `MatDatepicker` as:

```
onChange(value) {
   if(value === 'someValue'){
       this.datePicker.open();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You will need to get the datepicker in your code using `ViewChild` like this:

```
@ViewChild('picker') datePicker: MatDatepicker<Date>;
```

Then in your function, you can call the `open()` method of the datepicker:

```
onChange(value) {
   if(value === 'someValue'){
       this.datePicker.open();
   }
}
```

Link to [**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uu5wbn?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.ts).

Answer (score 2):

To those trying to get this to work on the latest version of Angular, you need to add a second argument to @ViewChild:

```
  @ViewChild('picker', {read: undefined, static: false}) datePicker: MatDatepicker<Date>;
```

And reference that object regularly in your function:

```
onChange(value) {
  if(value === 'someValue'){
    this.datePicker.open();
  }
}
```