# How to use angular material date picker without <mat-datepicker-toggle>

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I want to open a date picker when a user focuses on an input element. I don't want a toggle button.

```
<input
     matInput
     [matDatepicker]="picker"
     type="text"
     name="dob"
     #dob="ngModel"
     class="form-control"
     [(ngModel)]="details.dob"
     placeholder="Enter Date of Birth"
     readonly
 />
 <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

The above code does not provide this feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular material 2 date picker auto open on focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874705/angular-material-2-date-picker-auto-open-on-focus)

Comment: Call `picker.open()`

Comment: add  `(focus)="picker.open()"`

Answer (score 3):

Add the `focus` event with the handler which is **picker.open()**

```
<input
         matInput
         [matDatepicker]="picker"
         type="text"
         name="dob"
         #dob="ngModel"
         class="form-control"
         [(ngModel)]="details.dob"
         (focus)="picker.open()"
         placeholder="Enter Date of Birth"
         readonly
     />
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```